# Everything works fine but when I click edit button, a comma (,) is add every time. I would not find what going wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a note taking app. I have created Note And Board component. Everything works fine but when I click edit button, a comma (,) is add every time. I would not find what's going wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
class Note extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
   editing:true
  }
 }
 edit(){
  this.setState({editing: false});
 }
 save(){
  var val =this.refs.newText.value;
  console.log(this.refs.newText.value)
  this.props.onChange(val,this.props.index)
  this.setState({editing: true});
 }
 delete(){
  this.props.onRemove(this.props.index)
 }
 renderDisplay(){
  return(
    <div className="note">
     <p>{this.props.children}</p>
     <span>
      <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
      <button onClick={this.delete.bind(this)} className="danger">Delete</button>
     </span>
    </div>
   );
 }
 renderForm(){
  return(
    <div className="note">
     <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
     <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Save </button>
    </div>
   );
 }
 render(){
  // this.state.editing ? return this.renderDisplay() : return this.renderForm();
  if(this.state.editing){
   return this.renderDisplay();
  }else{
   return this.renderForm();
  }
 }
}

class Board extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
   notes: ["Hello"]
  }
 }
 update(newText,i){
  var arr = this.state.notes;
  arr[i]=newText;
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 remove(i){
  var arr =this.state.notes;
  arr.splice(i,1);
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 eachNote(note,i){
  return(
    <Note key={i} index={i} onChange={this.update.bind(this)} onRemove= {this.remove.bind(this)}> {note}</Note>
   )
 }
 add(text){
  // alert("hello");
  var arr = this.state.notes;
  arr.push(text);
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 render(){
  return <div className="board">
   <button onClick={this.add.bind(this,"New Note")}>Add</button><br/>
   {
    this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote.bind(this))
   }

  </div>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board ></Board>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;

}
body,html{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 height:100%;
}
.board{
 background:#fbd14b;
 height:100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width:100%;
 padding:20px;
}
.note{
 background:yellow;
 color: #333;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 min-height: 150px;
}
button{
 border:0;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background:#3ac569;
 color: #fff;
 margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
button:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.danger{
 background: #E71D36;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because of the space you provide before `{note}`,

```
<Note key={i} index={i} onChange={this.update.bind(this)} onRemove= {this.remove.bind(this)}> {note}</Note>
```

that changes `children` to `Note` in an array,

```
[' ', 'Hello']
```

So when you do `defaultValue = {this.props.children}`, it converts `array` to `string` by performing `this.props.children.join(',')` and that's how you are getting `,` in your result.

You can fix this by removing space before `{Note}`

```js
class Note extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super();
  this.state={
   editing:true
  }
 }
 edit(){
  this.setState({editing: false});
 }
 save(){
  var val =this.refs.newText.value;
  console.log(this.refs.newText.value)
  this.props.onChange(val,this.props.index)
  this.setState({editing: true});
 }
 delete(){
  this.props.onRemove(this.props.index)
 }
 renderDisplay(){
  return(
    <div className="note">
     <p>{this.props.children}</p>
     <span>
      <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
      <button onClick={this.delete.bind(this)} className="danger">Delete</button>
     </span>
    </div>
   );
 }
 renderForm(){
  return(
    <div className="note">
     <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
     <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Save </button>
    </div>
   );
 }
 render(){
  // this.state.editing ? return this.renderDisplay() : return this.renderForm();
  if(this.state.editing){
   return this.renderDisplay();
  }else{
   return this.renderForm();
  }
 }
}

class Board extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
   notes: ["Hello"]
  }
 }
 update(newText,i){
  var arr = this.state.notes;
  arr[i]=newText;
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 remove(i){
  var arr =this.state.notes;
  arr.splice(i,1);
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 eachNote(note,i){
  return(
    <Note key={i} index={i} onChange={this.update.bind(this)} onRemove= {this.remove.bind(this)}>{note}</Note>
   )
 }
 add(text){
  // alert("hello");
  var arr = this.state.notes;
  arr.push(text);
  this.setState({notes:arr});
 }
 render(){
  return <div className="board">
   <button onClick={this.add.bind(this,"New Note")}>Add</button><br/>
   {
    this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote.bind(this))
   }

  </div>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board ></Board>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;

}
body,html{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 height:100%;
}
.board{
 background:#fbd14b;
 height:100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width:100%;
 padding:20px;
}
.note{
 background:yellow;
 color: #333;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 min-height: 150px;
}
button{
 border:0;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background:#3ac569;
 color: #fff;
 margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
button:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.danger{
 background: #E71D36;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It really help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6ktw0ucm/1/

```
renderForm(){
    return(
            <div className="note">
                <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children[1]}></textarea>
                <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Save </button>
            </div>
        );
}
```